# Python Parsing Structured Text File

Tags: python, structured-data

I would like to parse in python a structured text file of the format:

```
[filter name_of_filter]
field1 = xxx, xxx
field2 = 23
```

The text file may contain other headers with different number of fields. To me the structure resembles a Windows ini file. I would like access to the data in the same way ConfigParser provides access i.e. be able to list sections, then for a given section see what the fields and their corresponding values are. The aim is to read the file, modify bits of it and write it back in the same format.

### Original Code

```
import ConfigParser as cp

config = cp.ConfigParser()
config.read('test')

print config.sections()
```

Output

```
[]
```

Where I went wrong was that no file called 'test' existed, lame error on my part.

### Background

Before posting I tried ConfigParser (as I had used it previously with .ini files a long time ago) but I couldn't get it to work. Google and SO led me to pyparser, but that seemed more at interpreting sentences and I couldn't figure out how to structure template for multiple lines. I was looking for something like ConfigParser and how it handles .ini files or BeautifulSoup does for html/xml documents or lxml for xml documents etc.

Unfortunately, I don't know what branch of programming / data processing this falls under nor the right keywords to use to identify a solution for myself. In my frustration I posted a question here.

### Acceptable Answers

Any of these are acceptable:

1. Show how ConfigParser can be used to tackle problem.
2. Alternatively if there is another module out there that can interpret this type of structured text file, state it and provide an example.

### Bonus Point

What branch of programming or data processing does this type of problem fall under? Where you have some data, you define a template or a template is automatically defined and then it is applied to access the data in a structured way.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the structure close enough to an ini file that the ConfigParser library would be able to handle the file? https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Comment: Did you try searching for "python parsing structured text file"?

Comment: Before posting this question, I was already aware of configparser and tried it myself but it didn't work as expected. Google and stack overflow led me to pyparser but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I've amended the question. I'm open to renaming the question if helps, more then happy to take suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly handle your example with [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html):

```
>>> txt='''\
... [filter name_of_filter]
... field1 = xxx, xxx
... field2 = 23'''
>>> import io
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
>>> config.readfp(io.BytesIO(txt))
>>> config.items("filter name_of_filter")
[('field1', 'xxx, xxx'), ('field2', '23')]
```

With a file:

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
with open(fn) as fin:
    config.readfp(fin)
    for section in config.sections():
        print '"{}":\t{}'.format(section, config.items(section))

# "filter name_of_filter":  [('field1', 'xxx, xxx'), ('field2', '23')]
```

If you want function *like* configparser without *using* configparser, I suppose start with the [source of configparser](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/configparser.py) as a reference. Specifically, you can [look at the regexes used](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/configparser.py#l537).

Comment: Thanks dawg! I did try ConfigParser but couldn't get it to work. I wasn't aware of the need for the allow_no_value=True and io.Bytes bits. Will read up and test before accepting.

Comment: @fswings: what does 'couldn't get it to work' mean in this case? I think if you are more specific with a new question I (or others) can help you. ConfigParser *does* work on the sample. Maybe supply a more specific sample and more specific desired output.

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could briefly state why io.BytesIO is required or wise to use.

Comment: In this case, `io.BytesIO` is simply being used to make an in-memory string look like a file. [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) is more commonly used for that purpose, but I used [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) since that is what is what was in the Python doc example for ConfigParser. The main thing to focus on here is the use of ConfigParser with a file...